# Default Value of DateTime in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to do a query on only questions that are not closed, and the ClosedDate query returns a DateTime object. I was wondering what the default value of DateTime was, as I can select only those with a DateTime of that. I looked on the documentation of T-SQL, and found it was 1900-01-01 00:00:00, but it only accepts the 1900-01-01 part in Data Explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ClosedDate` column is nullable, so questions which are not closed are simply posts meeting the criteria

```
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND ClosedDate IS NULL
```

…which I assume is what you were after.